# Zipping and encrypting files.

Tags: android, file, zip

What I would like to do is encrypt and zip files and store them on the sdcard of the device.

I haven't worked with raw files or zipping before so I have no idea where to start.

Is it possible to do on Android? I am using 4.0.3, would it be possible to zip like 1 gb folders? Or would I have to split them up into manageable chunks?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;import java.util.zip.*;
public class Zip {

  public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
    String[] source = new String[]{"C:/Users/MariaHussain/Desktop/hussain.java","C:/Users/MariaHussain/Desktop/aa.txt"};
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        String target = "C:/Users/MariaHussain/Desktop/target1.zip";
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(target));
        for (int i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(source[i]);

            // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(source[i]));

            // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            // Complete the entry
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
        }

        // Complete the ZIP file
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ZipInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and [ZipOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) stream to read write Zip files. Java doc page also has sample code for both reading and writing. And you can use android encryption library for encryption/decryption.